# Creating different activities for each item in a ListActivity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity

How can I create a new activity when an item in my ListView is clicked? It would be best if I can create this in a single java file. Also, it would be great if someone explained how I can display text in the new activity, I may be wrong, but I assume I can somehow use TextView. Any thought would be helpful, thanks in advance!

Comment: Capture the item click event and create an intent that contains the data that you need to send the new activity. Then start the activity with your intent as normal. This may prove useful: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/103/intent/412/passing-data-between-activities#t=201703142036175583965

Comment: You should google "start another activity" for a good tutorial about how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the item click event and create an intent that contains the data that you need to send the new activity. Then start the activity with your intent as normal.

`YourActivity.java`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourNextActivity.class);
            // Insert your logic to send data based on which item was clicked here
            intent.putExtra("MY_EXTRA_DATA", "Some data!");

            startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```

In the activity you start, you can use `getIntent()` to retrieve the data you pass in.

`YourNextActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String data = intent.getStringExtra("MY_EXTRA_DATA");

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourId);
    textView.setText(data);
}
```

Comment: What will happen if OP has multiple items?

Comment: He will need to use some logic to determine what data to send in place of `"Some data!"` based on which item is clicked

Comment: What about "Create this in a single Activity" ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If he's creating a new activity then creating a second file for that activity is the way to go

Comment: @AndrewBrooke I have 6 items in my ListView and want to display a different activity for each of those items. (Hope this clears things up)

Comment: Because if each activity he starts will be the same (besides the data he passes in), there is no reason to create a separate activity for each list item. It makes more sense to create a single activity, and always start that one, but pass in different data.

Comment: @programmingblues When you say different activity, what do you mean? If the layout for each one would be the same, you can use one activity, and pass in different pieces of data. If the activities are vastly different, it'd be better to create them separately.

Comment: The activities would be different in terms of only the text for each activity would be different for the specific item in the ListView. Does that make sense? @AndrewBrooke

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. In that case, my answer is basically what you would need.

Comment: @AndrewBrooke so let's say I had a list of apples, oranges, banana, grape, etc etc. The activity for the list would be a simple description of the those fruits

Comment: You're getting into the finer details of how it would need to be implemented, and how you store your data and display it is really up to you. The code I posted above demonstrates how to send the data between your activities, so I advise you try to adapt that to your situation.

Comment: @tahsinRupam you shouldn't have deleted your code because it was correct sir! Both answers are valid!